# Having issues with Twitter API authorization in Google Apps Script

Tags: json, google-apps-script, twitter-oauth

I've used the documentation posted here https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth1

I am having issues getting the function to authorize. I am new to working with API's so please bear with me. Trying to do a simple get request from twitter but the first part isn't going through. Any idea where things are going wrong? *Note ive loaded the Oauth1 library.

```
function getTwitterService() {
  // Create a new service with the given name. The name will be used when
  // persisting the authorized token, so ensure it is unique within the
  // scope of the property store.
  var service = OAuth1.createService('twitter')
      // Set the endpoint URLs.
      service.setAccessTokenUrl('https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token')
      service.setRequestTokenUrl('https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token')
      service.setAuthorizationUrl('https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize')

      // Set the consumer key and secret.
      service.setConsumerKey('myKey')
      service.setConsumerSecret('mySecret')

      // Set the name of the callback function in the script referenced
      // above that should be invoked to complete the OAuth flow.
      .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')

      // Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
      .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties());


function authCallback(request) {
 var twitterService = getTwitterService();
 var isAuthorized = twitterService.handleCallback(request);
  if (isAuthorized) {
  return Logger.log('Success! You can close this tab.');
  } else {
    return Logger.log('Denied. You can close this tab');
 }
}

function makeRequest() {
Logger.log(authorizationUrl);
  var twitterService = getTwitterService();
  var response = twitterService.fetch("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/list.json?screen_name='xyz'");
  var post = response.getContentText();
 Logger.log(post);
}
}
```

Comment: As @amit's answer indicates, if you open your Script Editor, highlight all your code, and press Tab to perform automatic, syntax-based indentation, you'll note that you've scoped your methods to within the `getTwitterService()` method.

Answer (score 1):

The getTwitterService() method should return the service object. 
Currently, all the other methods in the snippet are declared inside the getTwitterService method.

```
function getTwitterService() {
    return OAuth1.createService('twitter')
        .setAccessTokenUrl('https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token')
        .setRequestTokenUrl('https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token')
        .setAuthorizationUrl('https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize')
        .setConsumerKey('myKey')
        .setConsumerSecret('mySecret')
        .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')
        .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties());
}
```